# How can I remove empty lines from a file and write the non-empty lines back to the same file?

Tags: java

I am currently learning Java from a book and have come across an exercise which requires me to write a program that reads a file, removes any empty lines, and writes the non-empty lines back to the same file.

Since I couldn't find any information on how to do that, this is the code I wrote:

```
class Ask7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File inpFile = new File("textFile.txt");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("tempFile.txt");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(inpFile);

        while(in.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();

            if(line.length() > 0) {
                out.println(line);
            }
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Can you help me copy the contents of `tempFile.txt` to `inpFile.txt` and delete `tempFile.txt`, or suggest a better way to do it?

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Does it work? What happens when you run it and hat did you expect to happen instead? Did you see [deleting files in the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/delete.html)?

Comment: @Robert it works but not as it is asked. I should not return the output to a new file. I should rewrite the input file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have stated in your comment that the task is to rewrite the input file, you can use an approach like the one shown below:

```java
import java.io.*;

public class Ask7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Create a File object
        File textFile = new File("textFile.txt");

        // Create a BufferedReader object to read the contents of the file
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textFile));

        // Create a StringBuilder object to store the contents of the file
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        String line;

        // Loop through each line of the file
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Check if the line is not empty
            if (!line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                // If the line is not empty, append it to the StringBuilder object
                builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        }

        reader.close();

        // Create a FileWriter object to write to the same file
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(textFile);

        // Write the contents of the StringBuilder object to the file
        writer.write(builder.toString());

        writer.close();
    }
}
```

And a more concise, but also more complex, way to achieve the same outcome would be to utilize streams and collectors:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Ask7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
        // Create a Path object
        Path textFilePath = Paths.get("textFile.txt");
        
        // Read the contents of the file into a stream of lines using Files.lines()       
        String fileContents = Files.lines(textFilePath)
                                    // Filter out empty lines using the filter() method
                                    .filter(line -> !line.trim().isEmpty())
                                    // Collect the remaining non-empty lines into a single string, 
                                    // joining them together with newline characters between each line
                                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
                                    
        // Write the filtered contents to the same file using the Files.write() method,
        // after converting the string into a byte array using the getBytes() method,
        // because Files.write() expects data to be in this form
        Files.write(textFilePath, fileContents.getBytes());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I will read more about the BufferedReader.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably possible to read and write to the same file at the same time, but it overcomplicates the problem and is likely inefficient.

The simplest solution given the existing code is to take the current output file and overwrite the input file.  See [Files.copy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-).  The input and output files must be closed first.  See [Paths.get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) to build the Path objects.

Another option, if the input file fits in available memory, is to append the desired (non-blank) lines to a String or StringBuilder with carriage-returns (CR-LF or LF or [System.lineSeparator()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--)) appended after each line.  Then close the input file, reopen it for writing, and write the String using the something similar to the OP code or with something like [Files.write()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-).

Answer (score 0):

Writing to a temp file is good practice, especially if you might at some point process files large enough to impact server resources.  Java provides a function for creating temp files using a unique name to prevent possible collisions with other processes.  When your original file is fully processed, you replace the original with your temp file.

If something goes wrong during the process, your original will remain untouched, and you can inspect the temp file for clues.  Otherwise, your original will be replaced atomically (assuming your temp file and original file are on the same volume) with no chance that someone will read your partial file while you're still writing to it.

```
public static void removeBlanks(String filename) throws IOException {
    File temp = File.createTempFile("RemoveBlanks", null);
    File inpFile = new File(filename);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inpFile);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(temp);
    while(in.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        if(line.trim().length() > 0) {
            out.println(line);
        }
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
    Files.move(temp.toPath(), inpFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Comment: For small files, keeping the new results in memory and then overwriting the file is a decent approach.  The one you're suggesting, writing to a temp file and then moving it back to the original has many advantages, including less chance of corruption if a process is interrupted, and less chances of another process reading a file that is only partially written.

Comment: There is no need for blind trust.  [The documentation for Files.move](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) is very clear about how the method behaves.  File.renameTo is an ancient method that no one should use anymore.

Comment: @VGR.  Thanks.  Considering the improvements, I'm surprised it's not deprecated.